# How to stub getting user ip?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

My site needs to know user location. Using browser's geolocation API is not enough. So it takes user ip and uses geoip database to find out user location. But when I run tests, there's no such thing as client ip. Can I stub it somehow? Laravel's documentation [says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades) that one shouldn't stub (or to be precise, mock) `Request` facade. What do I do then?